# Program calculating sum, min, max values of user input

Tags: python, list, loops, sum

As the title says, I have created a program that does the following until the user presses the 'X' key. Which then stops and prints out all values in order. I also would like to mention that I can only use a specific compiler through my university, which registers the program as an error/wrong even though it should be correct.

**Edit:** Added the Status of the compiler.
[image: Compiler]

My question is, what other alternatives can I use to code a similar program, or any recommendations in general.

The requested input:

1

2

X

The requested output:

result:[1, 2]

average:1.50

min:1.00

max:2.00

[image: Screenshot of running program]

```
list1 = []
asknumber = str(0)
while asknumber != 'X':
  asknumber = input("Enter number: ")
  if asknumber == 'X':
    break
  list1.append(int(asknumber))
  big_value = max(list1)
  min_value = min(list1)
  average = sum(list1) / len(list1)
print("result:", sorted(list1))
print("average:", f'{average:.2f}')
print("min:", f'{min_value:.2f}')
print("max:", f'{big_value:.2f}')
```

Comment: How do you compile python? (as in -> is that even possible??)

Comment: Your code seems to produce the desired output.

Comment: @mama I think he's just referring to whatever grades the homework submission.

Comment: *which registers the program as an error* -> what is the error message?

Comment: BTW, you should calculate the results outside the loop. But this won't change the output.

Comment: Can the inputs be floating point? If so, you should use `float()` rather than `int()`.

Comment: Added a picture of the error message. I will try to to change the calculations outside the loop as you recommended, will also changing int() to float() instead.

Comment: @Ertu How about setting `sep=''` at each `print`; e.g., `print("result:", sorted(list1), sep='')`? The "requested output" does not have a blank after each colon.

Comment: @j1-lee, yo that actually might be it! That gave me some hope here, will try it out asap! :D

Comment: @j1-lee the program got accepted without any issues at all! Must say you have a very keen eye, appreciate everyone for their quick support!

Comment: @Ertu Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a computer is grading your work, the error is likely because you have spaces after your colons.

Someone suggested to use the following to resolve that issue:

```
print("result:", sorted(list1), sep='')
```

However, since you are already using f strings in your print statement, you might as well use them for all of it.

You also do not need to calculate the `min`, `max`, and `average` until the loop ends—and since you break the loop manually, you can just use `while True:`.

```
list1 = []
asknumber = str(0)
while True:
    asknumber = input("Enter number: ")
    if asknumber == 'X':
        break
    list1.append(int(asknumber))
big_value = max(list1)
min_value = min(list1)
average = sum(list1) / len(list1)
print(f'result:{sorted(list1)}')
print(f'average:{average:.2f}')
print(f'min:{min_value:.2f}')
print(f'max:{big_value:.2f}')
```

Comment: The error was exactly as you mentioned in the beginning, had done the changes before your comment and it got accepted on the first try. However, I also appreciate the other variation of the program u have posted. Will go through your program, and see the difference in order to learn better, thanks again!