# How do I initialize a name with the first non-zero digits input in Python

Tags: python

> Write a program to use a while loop to read the numbers from the user
> repeatedly until he/she inputs 0. Then report the sum of these numbers
> and the minimum value among them.

I just don't know how to initialize `smallest` with the first non-zero input.

```
total, smallest = 0, 0
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n == 0:
        break
    total += n
    if n < smallest:
        smallest = n
print("sum =", total)
print("min =", smallest)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Program calculating sum, min, max values of user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70103417/6045800)

Comment: Why not take the first input ***outside*** the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `smallest` equal to infinity (`inf`):

```
from cmath import inf #or "from math import inf"
total, smallest = 0, inf
```

test output:

```
3
7
9
2
0
sum = 21
min = 2
```

This means to matter what `n` is, it will all ways be smaller than `smaller` and thus:

```
if n < smallest: #this will always be true for the first non-zero n
        smallest = n #and will this "initialize" n
```

Another way to get this result would be to manually check `if smallest == 0`:

```
total, smallest = 0, 0
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if smallest == 0: #notice the addition here
        smallest = n #notice the addition here
    if n == 0:
        break
    total += n
    if n < smallest:
        smallest = n
print("sum =", total)
print("min =", smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `list` functions for that

```
l = []
while True:
    n = int(input())
    if n != 0:
        l.append(n)
    else:
        break 
print("sum =", sum(l))
print("min =", min(l))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.8 or greater, there is a convenient feature called the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) you can use to simplify things:

```
l = []
while(n := int(input())):
    l.append(n)

print("sum = ", sum(l))
print("min = ", min(l))
```

Test:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
0
sum =  55
min =  1
```

Answer (score -1):

It's quite simple. Just check if the current value of `smallest` is zero, if it is set it to be `n`. Else just go with the comparison statement(`if n<smallest:`)